# More then 2 for list statement

Tags: list, makefile

I want to make more then 2 lists in python script.
The first two is working but the thirt give me as result the last input of the list (OUT4)
Is this possible or must i change my code ??

```
# Main script
CSVlist = [CSV1, CSV2, CSV3, CSV4]
ANVlist = [ANV1, ANV2, ANV3, ANV4]
OUTlist = [OUT1, OUT2, OUT3, OUT4]
for CSVin in CSVlist:    
    for ANV in ANVlist:        
        for OUT in OUTlist:
            #data = [] #Buffer list
            if not os.path.exists(OUT):
                os.makedirs(OUT)

    print "--------------------------------"    
    print CSVin
    print
    print ANV
    print
    print OUT
    print "-------------------------------"
```

I hope you can understand my script..

Comment: you have an indention issue.

Comment: Yes ......stupid i did not see

Comment: What does this have to do with makefiles?